# I want to put my computational stuff in secondary thread while keeping main loop in main thread

Tags: c++, multithreading, opengl, boost, glut

I want to put my computational stuff in secondary thread while keeping main loop in main thread.

For example I want a cube rotating around OY with changing texture. Cube rotation is supported by ***idle*** function which rotates camera. But my texture computations are too complex and need some time so I cannot just put them into ***idle*** (I don't need to change the texture every time my cube rotates). Can I use ***foo*** function that does some computational stuff, creates texels buffer and sets new texture for the cube in a separate thread?
This piece of code from ***main*** function doesn't change texture of spinning cube.

```
glutIdleFunc(idle);
boost::thread_group tgroup;
tgroup.create_thread(boost::bind(&foo));
glutMainLoop();
tgroup.join_all();
```

Also are there concurrency problems with setting new texture in a different thread?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot call OpenGL functions from multiple threads generally speaking (without using multiple render contexts, or context switching).

You have to have a bound render context to issue OpenGL commands, and window systems will restrict you to a single context-per thread. To get around this, you are going to need to use a framework that is more advanced than GLUT. The basic idea is that you need to share resources between contexts, one for uploading data into and one for actually rendering.

But the more I think about this, there is no real reason for you to do any of this. Stick to using a single thread for all GL commands, maybe load image files from disk in another thread. And signal the thread that you do your rendering in to send the data to GL using `glTexImage2D (...)`. Your use-case is not complicated enough to warrant multi-threaded rendering, to be honest.

Answer (score 5):

While it is not possible to call OpenGL operations on a given context from several threads at a time, it is possible to offload texture buffer manipulations to another thread using a mapped PBO.

In your (main) OpenGL thread allocate a pixel buffer object (PBO) with the right size for your texture's data and map it into process memory. The usage pattern in this case will be, that the PBO acts a short term intermediary for the data, i.e. upload into that buffer followed by an OpenGL access to that buffer, followed by either buffer deletion, or data change; this is the STREAM usage pattern.

```
GLuint pboID;
glGenBuffers(1, &pboID);
glBindBuffer(GL_PIXEL_UNPACK_BUFFER, pboID);
glBufferData(GL_PIXEL_UNPACk_BUFFER, size, NULL, GL_STREAM_DRAW);
void *buffermap = glMapBuffer(GL_PIXEL_UNPACK_BUFFER, GL_WRITE_ONLY);
glBindBuffer(GL_PIXEL_UNPACk_BUFFER, 0); /* the memory mapping is preserved */

/* queue that pbo for the worker thread to work upon */
```

You can now write values into the memory area pointed to by `buffermap`; every thread can do this. Once you're done with updating the buffer unmap it and use it to load data into the texture. When there's a pixel unpack buffer bound, the data parameter to `glTex[Sub]Image` turns into a 0-based offset parameter, designating the offset position within the buffer object from which to source the data.

```
if( workerthread_is_done ) {
    glBindBuffer(GL_PIXEL_UNPACK_BUFFER, pboID);
    glUnmapBuffer(GL_PIXEL_UNPACK_BUFFER);

    /* prepare a texture object as usual */
    glTex[Sub]Image2D(…, NULL);

    glBindBuffer(GL_PIXEL_UNPACK_BUFFER, 0);
}
```

You can now either delete the PBO *pboID* or reuse it by supplying it with new data.

Answer (score 0):

You can't multithread OpenGL calls. However, if you wanted to, you could perhaps precompute the texture calculations without using OpenGL code, and then put the results in the main thread for OpenGL to grab.